# Php file_get_contents() issue

Tags: php

With php file_get_contents() i want just only the post and image. But it's get whole page. (I know there is other way to do this)

Example:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.bdnews24.com/details.php?cid=2&id=221107&hb=5', 
true);
echo $homepage;
```

It's show full page. Is there any way to show only the post which cid=2&id=221107&hb=5.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, I'm new in php, i just want the specific post and image but it's show full page.

Comment: have fun parsing that table...

Comment: Have you considered their RSS feed? http://rss.bdnews24.com/rss/english/home/rss.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's [DomDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) to parse the page. You can filter it more if you wish, but this is the general idea.

```
$url = 'http://www.bdnews24.com/details.php?cid=2&id=221107&hb=5';
// Create new DomDocument
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);


// Get the post
$post = $doc->getElementById('opage_mid_left');


var_dump($post);
```

---

Update:
Unless the image is a requirement, I'd use the printer-friendly version: http://www.bdnews24.com/pdetails.php?id=221107, it's much cleaner.

Comment: Then go with the first version and strip out the elements you don't want

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse the resulting HTML using a DOM parser to get the HTML of only the part you want. I like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), but as Paul pointed out, [PHP also has it's own](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Although you may as well use PHP's built in DOMDocument as it's *probably* more efficient.

Comment: @PaulBain either way, it's always nice to have options. Added to the answer.

Comment: True, although the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser uses regex to parse the DOM, and I'm *sure* someone will point you to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: @PaulBain haha, I actually commented this on PsyCoder's answer half an hour ago. Wasn't aware it used regexes.

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the

```
<div id="page">
      //POST AND IMAGE EXIST HERE
</div>
```

part from the fetched contents using regex and push it on your page...